# How to access factory from controller

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have a `factory` like this:

```
rasm.factory('serviceUrl',[function(){
        function serviceUrl(){
            this.p = location.protocol;
            this.h = getHost();
        }
        serviceUrl.prototype.getServiceUrl = function(){
            return this.p +'//'+ this.h + '/services/'
        }
    }])
```

i have implemented this in javascript object oriented way.this is the resource that i have used
https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-model-objects-with-javascript-classes-2e6a067c73bc#.du8tor7h2

My problem is, how can I access this **getServiceUrl** function from my controller. is this even possible? thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read about [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). You first need to change that factory code:

```
rasm.factory('serviceUrl',[function(){
    function serviceUrl(){
        this.p = location.protocol;
        this.h = getHost();
    }
    serviceUrl.prototype.getServiceUrl = function(){
        return this.p +'//'+ this.h + '/services/'
    }

    // This line has been added
    return serviceUrl;
}]);
```

Then use it in your controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'serviceUrl', function($scope, serviceUrl) {

     serviceUrl.getServiceUrl();
}]);
```

**Update**

I suggest you changing your factory code like this:

```
rasm.factory('serviceUrl', [function() {
    var _this = this;

    _this.p = location.protocol;
    _this.h = getHost();

    return {
        getServiceUrl: function() {
            return _this.p +'//'+ _this.h + '/services/'
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: i thought i have to create object from serviceUrl. like this **var obj = new serviceUrl();  obj.getServiceUrl()**

Comment: No, factories in Angular are singleton throughout the lifecycle of your app that means Angular do the same (`new serviceUrl`) internally only once then the same instance is made available everywhere using DI.

Comment: actually this is not true, angular does not call the NEW for factories, but only executes the recipe as it is returning (and caching) the result. in this case i think is more appropriate using a service.

Comment: @Shashank Agrawal it gives me this error **serviceUrl.getServiceUrl is not a function**